# Visual Studio Code: How to show Overloads in IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am working with the new asp.net core 1.0 framework on Visual Studio Code.

My question is, how do I traverse through all the overloads a method might have?

[image: VS Code method overloads]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When at that stage you can just press `(` and it will prompt you for the overloads.

Take this example:

[image]

I press `(` and I get:

[image]

If I happen to change focus, I can go back into the call at `this.M1(` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on macOS) to get the overload prompt again:

[image]

Pretty much the same as Visual Studio.

This is in VS Code 1.7.1, C# 1.4.1 extension.

Comment: Thank you. Hitting `(` after the method name did the trick, and I can use `up` and `down` arrow keys to navigate between overloads.

Comment: I found that I can use `Ctrl+Shift+Space` thanks to your answer.

Comment: @Qwerty I think you should write it as an answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: With the vim extension enabled, none of the above suggestions are working for me. "(" navigates to the beginning of the current sentence and Ctrl+Shift+Space hides the IntelliSense dropdown. I guess this requires another workaround ontop in my case.

Comment: Is there a key binding for next/previous overload, so I don't have to use the mouse to click on the arrows above and below '1/2'?

Comment: @wensveen I just found the answer. It's up and down arrow, but down is next and up is previous. After the last overload (or before the previous), the hints window closes.

Comment: `cmd+shift+Space` in mac :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this by hovering your mouse over a function? It pops up a very similar window, but I don't know how to see the overloads in it

Comment: @wensveen THX a lot! For me, this would be the actual answer as `Ctrl+Shift+Space` opens the tool tip. But clarification on the fragile way the arrow keys are used to actually iterate the overloads is the answer I was looking for. (@DaveShaw maybe you'd like to add @wensveen s comment to your answer)

Comment: Is there the way to insert code from overloads hint? I have to type it by myself but it seems there should be the way to take it at once from hint...

Answer (score 11):

I can't comment on the accepted answer but in case anyone has the problem Dawson B mentioned, where you can't navigate the little window of overloads with the vim extension enabled, I found a solution. It was difficult to figure out what that window is called as it's not easy to google, but it is apparently a `ParameterHint`.

Open the Keyboard Shortcuts with `Ctrl+K Ctrl+S`, search for "hint", click the pencil to the left of `showNextParameterHint`, change to `Alt+N`, and `showPrevParameterHint` to `Alt+P`, to not interfere with the `Ctrl+N/P` binding to Intellisense suggestion navigation. Of course if these conflict with some other extension/custom binding you have, pick whatever works best.

Comment: Really useful the tip to go into the keyboard shortcuts and change the values for those parameters, it did the trick for me. +1