# How to make IntelliSense show the parameters of a function in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make Intellisense show up the function parameters once the parentheses are written down? It shows only if I just type them like in the tutorial example, but not once they are already written and I set the cursor with the mouse inside.
[image: VSCode Intellisence]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: How to show Overloads in IntelliSense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453617/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-overloads-in-intellisense)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want the **Trigger Parameter Hints** command. If you type it in the command palette it will show your current short-cut (mine is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).