# "Show hover" fails inside function arguments (vscode python intellisense)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working in python using vscode.
My current vscode setup shows very nice, useful information when my cursor is on a function and I trigger `editor.action.showHover` (for me this is mapped to `Shift+Tab`).  However, when I'm inside the function arguments and I hit `Shift+Tab` it doesn't work.  I checked the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` and it shows me the error:

```
2023-05-07 11:13:06.535 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Tab]
2023-05-07 11:13:06.535 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 8 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.showHover, when: editorTextFocus, source: user.
2023-05-07 11:13:06.535 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.showHover.
2023-05-07 11:13:06.535 [error] Unhandled method getIdAtPosition: Error: Unhandled method getIdAtPosition
    at /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples-0.2.7/dist/extension.js:2:406156
    at /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples-0.2.7/dist/extension.js:2:406450
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples-0.2.7/dist/extension.js:2:406812)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

Sometimes it does seem to work, except using `Trigger Parameter Hints`, instead of `Show Hover`.  This is what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62680065/230468), but at least for my configuration the `Trigger Parameter Hints` is really unhelpful, especially compared to the `Show Hover` output, and it still doesn't show up consistently.

Is there a way to get `Show Hover` to trigger from within function parenthesis?

Edit: It's also unclear why Parameter Hints are being triggered at all.  under keyboard shortcuts I see a `pylance.triggerParameterHints` that has no keybinding.  And nothing else relevant is set to `Shift+Tab` besides `showHover`.

Comment: According to the error message, you should have the **IntelliCode API Usage Examples** extension installed. Disable this extension to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @JialeDu disabling API Usage Examples doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) expressing your desired effect?